# How to keep track of only one image in ARKit Image detection

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, scenekit, arkit

I’m building an image tracking app which displays a plane with AV Player to play a video on top of the image using SCNPlane. When user swipes to next image then next video will play. I was able to find implement it by adding video plane on top of the detected image inside didAddNode method but it works only when user swipes till end image for first time. If user comes again to same image it does not work because didAddNode is not called for already seen image instead didUpdate is getting called. Can I make to keep track of only one image at a time so that didAdd will be fired when ever it sees an another image irrespective of already tracked or not

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the below implementation inside didUpdate function

```
if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor, imageAnchor.isTracked == false {
  self.sceneView.session.remove(anchor: anchor)
}
```